# C# The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

I searched a lot on the internet. most answers are to add reference. But once I add reference, it doesn't allow me to do this and need me to remove Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook firstly. But I cannot find Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook in my reference list.

how can I deal with it ?
Need your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have office installed into your system?

Comment: Is the .net framework version in your project set properly?

Comment: Install Office  in system

Comment: You dont need Complete MS Office for this. You should get Microsoft Office PIA for the relevant version of Office suite.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you follow it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects ,it work for me

Comment: Could you add specifically what helped you alongside your link? Otherwise answer is hard to understand